# C recursion return 2 values

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am trying to return sums of digits of 2 numbers using recursion. I think my algorithm is OK, but I am not so good with pointers and I don't understand why they are showing weird values (like when variable is not declared) when they point to variables declared in `main` and they are `0`.

Here is my code:

```
int get_sums(int **fp, int **sp, int n1, int n2) {
    printf("fp: %d\n", fp);
    printf("sp: %d\n", sp);
    printf("n1: %d\n", n1);
    printf("n2: %d\n", n2);

    if (n1 == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    *fp += (n1 % 10);
    *sp += (n2 % 10);

    return get_sums(&fp, &sp, n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
}

int main(void) {
    int f = 0, s = 0;
    int *fp = &f;
    int *sp = &s;
    int first = 123, second = 456;

    get_sums(&fp, &sp, first, second);
    printf("First sum: %d\nSecond sum: %d\n", *fp, *sp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What to do if the numbers have different numbers of digit?

Comment: I solved that problem before, they will always have same number of digits, hardcoded number values just for example. I only need help on my recursion.

Comment: A simpler solution would be to rewrite get_sums() to handle just one number, and then call get_sums() twice. Then you can use get_sums' return value to add up stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple problems:

- you are using 2 levels of indirection where one would suffice
- you do not dereference the pointers to pass the values to `printf`
- you should just pass the pointers recursively instead of their addresses, but invoke the function with the addresses of the results.
- you should recurse until both numbers are completely decimated
- you should enable more warnings for the compiler to help you avoid such mistakes: `gcc -Wall` for example.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_sums(int *fp, int *sp, int n1, int n2) {
    printf("fp: %d\n", *fp);
    printf("sp: %d\n", *sp);
    printf("n1: %d\n", n1);
    printf("n2: %d\n", n2);

    if (n1 == 0 && n2 == 0) {
        return;
    }

    *fp += n1 % 10;
    *sp += n2 % 10;

    get_sums(fp, sp, n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
}

int main(void) {
    int f = 0, s = 0;
    int first = 123, second = 456;

    get_sums(&f, &s, first, second);
    printf("First sum: %d\nSecond sum: %d\n", f, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Very nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You need not to pass the pointers by pointers.:)

Take into account that the function will always return 0.

It can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_sums( int *fp, int *sp, int n1, int n2) 
{
    printf("fp: %d\n", *fp);
    printf("sp: %d\n", *sp);
    printf("n1: %d\n", n1);
    printf("n2: %d\n", n2);

    if ( n1 != 0 && n2 != 0 )
    {
        *fp += (n1 % 10);
        *sp += (n2 % 10);

        get_sums( fp,  sp, n1 / 10, n2 / 10);
    }
}   

int main(void) 
{
    int f = 0, s = 0;   
    int *fp = &f;
    int *sp = &s;

    int first = 123, second = 456;

    get_sums( fp, sp, first, second);
    printf("First sum: %d\nSecond sum: %d\n", *fp, *sp);
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
fp: 0
sp: 0
n1: 123
n2: 456
fp: 3
sp: 6
n1: 12
n2: 45
fp: 5
sp: 11
n1: 1
n2: 4
fp: 6
sp: 15
n1: 0
n2: 0
First sum: 6
Second sum: 15
```